# ASP.NET MVC background image

Tags: css, image, background

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET MVC. I'm trying to make a decent site, and I've encountered a stupid problem:
I can't set the background to be a local image.

in Site.css, this works:

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background-image: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/zJj7EIt.jpg);
}
```

but I don't want the image be an URL.

I've tried the following things:

Number one:

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background-image: 
url( C:\Users\alexh\Documents\GitHub\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\Styles\Images\background.jpg)
}
```

Number two:

```
<body style="background-image: 
url( C:\Users\alexh\Documents\GitHub\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\Styles\Images\background.jpg)">
```

Number three(which is obsolete):

```
<body background="C:\Users\alexh\Documents\GitHub\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\StupidASP.NET\Styles\Images\background.jpg">
```

I must miss something related to resources, and not with properties. Do you have any solution or idea? Or an explication about what vs does.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with ASP, it is a simple HTML/CSS issue. Have you checked the browser console to see if it has anything to say about this? // You should not try and embed stuff into a page via the local file system in the first place, but rather use a relative URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an absolute path. Use a relative path.

if your css file is located here for instance (from the root of your site): 
`/Styles/Site.css`

then your CSS should be:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-image:url(Images/background.jpg)
}
```

so, you're saying from where your css file is (`/Styles`) your image file is a sub-directory of this (`/Styles/Images/[the-filename-for-your-image]`).

Also, not the use of `/` rather than `\` in your image path

Answer (score 1):

Here, the problem is it's not picking the exact file mentioned in the `url()`, so just try the below scenario.

Create a folder with name `Images` inside your project folder and then copy all the images into it.

then your css should be

```
background-image: url('Images/imageFile.png');
```

this `url` location means from the `root` of your project there should be one folder with name `Images` and inside it there should be the mentioned image file.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'number two' should be like next line, at least the line works with me like this:

```
<body style="background-image: url( ~/Images/background.jpg)"/>
```